# Image.xcassets issue with displaying splashes for devices with iOS 8

Tags: ios, xcode6.1

Which images I should use if I only need to support landscape orientation and devices with iOS 7 and upper?

I have unselected all unneeded checkboxes, but the loading image does not appear for example on simulator 4s or 5 (c,s)? It only appears on iPhone 6 plus simulator. What can be a problem?

[image]

Comment: Well, this makes sense, because an iPhone 4s or 5 is not a Retina HD 5.5, is it? It's hard to see, based on your screen shot, what else you expect.

Comment: @matt yes it is ) but if you can see the checkmarks specified for landscape, but there are no additional options to set for example 4'' or 4.7 inches for landscape mode. Does it mean that I should check portraits checkmarks? In this case what those checkmarks allow?

Comment: Yes, just use the portrait ones. They will be turned sideways. :)

Comment: @matt but in the projects settings I just set landscape orientation and when I even use portrait it does not appear for me

Comment: @matt, so there is no default screen at start, I've put Retina 4.7 HD, but no image when app is loading

Comment: Oh, yes, it's a bug. :)

Comment: @matt, maybe I should use then xib for iPhone 6 Plus, but for what purposes then we use it in xcassets, is this bug only for simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered a bug with asset catalogs. You can't use an asset catalog to provide a launch image for an app that launches into landscape. To do what you're trying to do, you'll need to use the old-fashioned "named" launch images at the top level of your app bundle.

Comment: thank you for help, I have deleted "Launch screen interface file base name" from info.plist and right now it works. Seems my issue was based on the fact that iOS 8 uses xib file for loading image. So I just deleted xib, but I have not deleted line from plist, that's why I didn't see splash.

Comment: Yes, iOS 7 doesn't have launch screens so you have to use launch images only.

Comment: hm, but if i remove checkbox portrait in the "General" tab. It does not work again )))

Comment: Because there's a bug with asset catalogs. I already explained that to you.

Comment: you're right this is a bug. so I suggest my latest apps which have run on iOS8 never shown splashes. omg. weird.

Comment: My attitude is: this is Apple's bug. The apps get through the App Store verification process just fine. It's the fault of the _system_. If the system doesn't want to show my launch image, that's Apple's problem. :) Please feel free to file a duplicate bug report.

Comment: I was able to fix this in my own testing, just as I said in my answer: I put a file called _LaunchImage@2x.png_ in my app bundle and told the _Info.plist_ that the launch image was called "LaunchImage", and sure enough, the launch image appeared in my app on iPhone 4s even though it launches in landscape. So, I believe I have proved that I have answered your question correctly.

Comment: sure thank you a lot! ) as I understood I need to keep images assets files for splashes as well? am I right?

Comment: Just found this sample code that tells you what to do: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Icons/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010442-ReadMe_txt-DontLinkElementID_3